# Question on limit of a function of a sequence

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Let $f$ be a continuous real valued function on $[0,+\infty)$. Let $A$
>   be the set of real numbers $a$ that can be expressed as $$a = \lim_{n
>  \to \infty}f(x_n)$$ for some sequence $(x_n)$ in $[0,+\infty)$ such
>   that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=+\infty$. Prove that if $A$ contains
>   the two numbers $a$ and $b$, then it contains the entire interval with
>   endpoints $a$ and $b$.

I am not looking for hints or answers to the problem. I don't understand how it is possible for $f$ to converge to different values when $\{x_n \}\to +\infty$.  Isn't $ \lim_{n
 \to \infty}f(x_n)$ equivalent to $ \lim_{x
 \to \infty}f(x)$ ?
Or is it possible that we have to consider a convergent subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ so that $x_{n_k} \to x_0$ and then $a=\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$?

Comment: A quick example: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(n\pi)=0$, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin((2n+0.5)\pi)=1$

Comment: The question is talking about the $a$ you can get from all possible convergent sequences $(x_n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good example was made in the comment and as mentioned any periodic function such as the function $\sin(x)$ does not converge because the function repeats its values in periods.

Hence, we cannot conclude that such a periodic function $f(x)$ would converge to only a specific value as $x\rightarrow \infty$. However, since it is periodic, we do know that even as $x$ tends to infinity, it would still take on the interval of values from the period.

Since the function mentioned is continuous, you can most likely use the intermediate value theorem to prove the claim.